# removeFilter() function not working in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have a removeFilter() javascript function in my application and it is not getting invoked for some reason and throwing the following error ONLY in IE9. I initially thought it be some typo in my invocation code but when i simple change the name to something other than removeFilter() (say for example applyFilter()) the function seems to be working fine. I simple tried printing some alerts within the function and the function was not invoked. Please note the function works fine in other IE 7, IE8.

ERRROR: SCRIPT65535: Argument not optional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://www.jabcreations.com/blog/internet-explorer-9 -- evidently removeFilter (and addFilter) are among a list of reserved functions in IE 9.