# SCRIPT16385: Not implemented

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The following code works fine on Chrome and FireFox, but it doesn't work properly on IE:

```
if (jQuery.trim(jQuery("#"+element_id.name).val()) != "" && jQuery.trim(jQuery("#"+element_id.name).val()) != "0") {
  jQuery("#filters-box").append('<span id="filter-'+ element_id.name +'" class="toggler"><button class="button white" onClick="removeFilter(\'filter-' + element_id.name + '\')"> ✖ </button>' + document.getElementById(element_id.name + "_caption" ).value + ' -> ' + document.getElementById(element_id.name).value + '</span>');
}
```

Though it can append the HTML code and render them on the page properly, but its onClick event generates the above error message.

Comment: can you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) where we can see the issue ?

Comment: + what exactly does the `removeFilter` do? can you show it's source code?

Comment: /*
 Remove filter 
 */
 function removeFilter(filter_id) {
     var elementid = filter_id.replace("filter-", "");
     
     removeFilterBefore(elementid);
     
     //remove filter key and value
     delete filters[elementid.replace("list_", "")];
     
     //remove filter button from filters' box
     jQuery("#"+filter_id).remove();
     
     //enable its respective dropdown list
     jQuery("#"+elementid).prop("disabled", false);
     
     removeFilterAfter(elementid);
 }

Comment: possible duplicate of [removeFilter() function not working in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463032/removefilter-function-not-working-in-ie9)

Answer (score 4):

Strangely i have tried changing your function name "removeFilter" and it works absolutely fine
Please find the change

```js
var element_id = {
  name: "test",
  "test_caption": "_caption"
};

function rmvFilter(ele) {

  alert(ele);
}

var html = '<span id="filter-' + element_id.name + '" class="toggler">';
html += '<button class="button white" id="button" onClick="rmvFilter(\'caption_' + element_id.name + '\');"> ✖ </button></span>';
jQuery("#filters-box").append(html);
```

I dont find any error in your code except that the exact combination of name isn't strangely working in IE9 only

Answer (score 1):

If you precompile the string with jQuery you can attach events as if it were already in the DOM (basically). This is cleaner, non-obtrusive and should work in all browsers supported by jQuery:

```
if (jQuery.trim(jQuery("#"+element_id.name).val()) 
    != "" && jQuery.trim(jQuery("#"+element_id.name).val()) != "0") {

    // precompile to a temp var
    var $temp = jQuery('<span id="filter-'+ element_id.name +'" class="toggler"><button class="button white"> ✖ </button>' + document.getElementById(element_id.name + "_caption" ).value + ' -> ' + document.getElementById(element_id.name).value + '</span>');

    // this works fine
    $temp.find('button.button.white').on('click', function () { removeFilter('filter-' + element_id.name); });

    jQuery("#filters-box").append($temp);
}
```

Comment: @Agilox good to know! correct answer / +1 will be much appreciated :)

Comment: in the same version or different versions? using jQuery has the advantage of abstracting the browser out, so no matter what browser (or version of said browser), if it's supported by jQuery it'll probably work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to you, Kartheek. I just ran into the same problem with a function called "removeFilter(event)" in IE9 (it worked fine in Firefox and Chrome) and changing the function name worked for me too.

I can only assume this was some kind of built-in function for IE which had not been implemented as of IE9, so the browser calls the wrong function which throws its not-implemented error.

Comment: Please do not add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, when you have enough reputation, you can [upvote helpful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or [award a bounty to helpful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).